# How to get multi table and paste to multi dropdowListFor on view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag, multi-table

I'm newbie ASP.NET MVC.

I have many table such as (Country, State and city).
I want to put value in these DropDownListFor in one view.
Could you help me please.

Sorry for my bad question and bad English skill.

Answer (score 0):

Use viewmodel using all properties from all table

```
public class dataViewModel
{
public string country { get; set; }
public string state{ get; set; }
//all other properties from other class
}
```

refer the viewmodel in the View.

Comment: You meaning to create new viewmodel and collect other table viewmodel?

Comment: yes and if any extra operation needed like selecting state via zip code pass it as viewbag from actionresult